# Optional Argument parameter when setting up argo workflow

Tags: argo-workflows

I have following argo workflow parameters

```
spec:
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: housename
        description: name of house
      - name: total
        description: total house you owe
```

Down in line, I will be creating task but I want to make total as optional parameter

Comment: I think this is not possible. The only case where a parameter can be not defined in `spec.arguments.parameters` is when it has a default value.